# Make transit stations clickable

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How do I make transit stations clickable on a default implementation of Maps?

Quite like this one:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple

One would expect stations to be clickable, as they are on Google Maps, the website itself. Why aren't they when embedded via the API, and how do I make it work anyway?

It's gotta be a flag or something, somewhere, but I have no idea where to look for something like, what it's called, or how to supply it to the API...

~~~EDIT~~~

Here's a test I made:
http://home.thany.nl/apps/MYMaps/test2.html

It's using the Places API to find train stations and mark them clickable. Works somewhat. It's still horrible, as the Places API doesn't know which language of a train station POI to return (so it returns both English and Japanese for some) and it doesn't know about the map zoom level, so it happily skips train stations that have icons visible on the map, and vice versa.

So all in all, Places API is not a great way of working around this problem. I need what Google Maps has, or **at least** have train/subway stations be clickable.

Comment: What Google did on their maps.google.com website is their implementation of the API (presumably). That does **not** mean you will find the same behaviour/features by implementing the API on your website.

Comment: So then, the question is: how do I do what Google did to make transit stations clickable?

Comment: Short answer: You can't. This information is not available through the API. Longer answer: implement your own markers with your own data.

Comment: I find that extremely hard to believe, especially since Google Maps itself is supposedly made using the very same API. Besides, I don't have locations of every train&subway station in the world, Google does.

Comment: @MrUpsidown also see the test I made

Comment: Yes, through the Places library, you can get `train_station` and other types. But I suppose one would expect the icons to be clickable (as they are on maps.google.com) like other POI that are displayed using the API. https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=145 I suppose you are the last one who commented on that? As you can see, the feature request dates back from early 2008. Like many other feature requests unfortunately!

Comment: Well, as you can see in my example, the Places API is not a very good solution. It's also not what Google Maps itself uses (unsurprizingly).

Comment: I'm actually exploring Bing Maps, but Bing has similar problems :(

Comment: If anyone has another idea, feel free to share it. I'm still exploring what's the best way to go, with clikable POI's that include transit stations...

Comment: This question is still active. Google didn't bother to enable this in the new version. I still need this.